# What careless mistake did this step take?

Tags: calculus

Suppose $f = \frac{(1/2)^n}{1+(1/2)^n}$ where $n \geq 1 $ I wanted to give an upper bound the function.

So I did

$f = \frac{(1/2)^n}{1+(1/2)^n} \leq \frac{(1/2)^n}{(1/2)^n} = 1$

Which is right, but then I also did

$f = \frac{(1/2)^n}{1+(1/2)^n} \leq \frac{(1/2)^n}{(1)} = (1/2)^n$ and as $n\to \infty$, the function is bounded by $0$ and this makes no sense at all. I have no idea what I am doing wrong in my algebra, but the solution makes no sense ot me, I couldn't interpret the answer at all

Comment: You showed $\lim_{n\to\infty}f=0$, which makes perfect sense. You found a _lower_ bound for all $n$ while the first step you found an _upper_ bound for all $n$.

Comment: Write it as $f(n)\le (1/2)^n$. What you've shown is that the limit of $f$ as $n$ tends to $\infty$ is $0$. Of course, this doesn't mean that $f$ is always less than or equal to $0$.

Comment: So it is always bounded by 1 for all n. And then as n gets larger you can get another smaller and smaller bound which is going to zero. Being bounded by 1/128 and by 1 simultaneously is no contradiction.

Comment: What happens if i replace (1/2) by (-1/2)? What is behavior and bound then?

Comment: @Clayton He did not find a lower bound for all n.

Comment: @CalvinLin: It's a trivial lower bound, but a lower bound nonetheless. All terms are positive, hence necessarily nonnegative.

Comment: @sizz: See Marvis' edit to address your more general question.

Comment: @Clayton What I meant was that the second step: $f \leq (1/2)^n$ did not determine a lower bound. However, saying that all the terms are positive provides the lower bound.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why doesn't it make sense? What you have written is correct. In fact,
$$0 \leq \dfrac{a^n}{1+a^n} \leq a^n$$ is true for all $a \geq 0$. Hence, if $a < 1$, we have that $$\lim_{n \to \infty} \dfrac{a^n}{1+a^n} = 0$$

**EDIT**

For $a < 0$, we will split it into three cases.
For $a \in (-1,0)$, we have $$\lim_{n \to \infty} \dfrac{a^n}{1+a^n} = \dfrac{\lim_{n \to \infty} a^n}{1+ \lim_{n \to \infty} a^n} = 0$$

For $a \in (-\infty,-1)$, we have $$\dfrac{a^n}{1+a^n} = \dfrac1{1+\left(\dfrac1a \right)^n}$$
Hence, $$\lim_{n \to \infty} \dfrac{a^n}{1+a^n} = \lim_{n \to \infty} \dfrac1{1+\left(\dfrac1a \right)^n} = \dfrac1{1+\lim_{n \to \infty} \left(\dfrac1a \right)^n} = 1$$

For $a=-1$, for even $n$, we have $$\dfrac{(-1)^{2k}}{1+(-1)^{2k}} = \dfrac12$$

For $a=-1$, for odd $n$, it blows up.

For $a=-1+\epsilon$, for odd $n$, we have $$\lim_{\epsilon \to 0^+} \dfrac{(-1+ \epsilon)^{2k+1}}{1+(-1+ \epsilon)^{2k+1}} = -\infty$$

For $a=-1-\epsilon$, for odd $n$, we have $$\lim_{\epsilon \to 0^+} \dfrac{(-1- \epsilon)^{2k+1}}{1+(-1- \epsilon)^{2k+1}} = +\infty$$

Comment: Oh I didn't look at the lower bound. Initally I thought I have a sum of positive numbers less than 0. What is the behaviour if $a < 0$?

Comment: @sizz Have updated the behavior for $a < 0$.

Comment: What was the problem of just going straight into $n = 2k+1$? What's the small epsilon for?

Comment: @sizz for $n=2k+1$, the expression $\dfrac{a^{2k+1}}{1+a^{2k+1}}$ blows up. What I wanted to convey ws that if you approach from the right of $1$ for an odd $n$, it blows to $-\infty$ while approach from left, it blows to $+\infty$.

Comment: Sorry I just want to ask for the case when $a \in (-1, 0)$ Why does $a^n \to 0$ again? Does it have to do with the geometric series' convergence of $|a| < 1$??

Comment: @sizz If $a \in (-1,1)$, then $a^n \to 0$.

Comment: For the case of $a = -1$ where the exponent is odd, the limit simply doesn't exist right? It's not infinity or -infinity

Comment: For $a=-1$, the limit doesn't exist since for even $n$ it is $1/2$, while for odd $n$ it blows up.

Comment: It blows up in "both" directions right?

Comment: Oh wait that's why you did the epsilon thing okay

Comment: @sizz Yes. We want to study how the function behave as we approach $-1$ from both sides and thats why I did the epsilon thing.

Answer (score 2):

But you are correct! You made no mistake.  Consider: when $n$ is large, $(1/2)^n$ is very close to 0, and $1+(1/2)^n$ is close to 1.  Then their quotient is close to 0.

For example, take $n=20$.  Then you have $$f(n) = \frac{0.00000095367431640625}{1.00000095367431640625} = 0.00000095367340691241.$$